How to use Theia's premade EditorWidget inside custom React widget?
I want to use theia's EditorWidget inside a React widget that I wrote, like this

When I started the base theia app it came with a file explorer, and if you make a json file and open it there is a nice easy code editor to edit the json. How do I put that in the html code for my widget and pass data to it?
The common advice seems to be either 'include it in the package.json and it will magically appear' (s) or 'here's how to make custom code based on theia extensions'. It also seems like you can't position any of these default theia widgets beyond their 'four panels' layout.
